# Retrieving Current Time from Carrier in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, core-telephony

Is there is any way to get the current time from the Carrier. Like Auto Update time, Even if the Auto Update of time is Off from settings. Even if the Internet connection is not available.

Comment: Have you got solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe take a look at [iOS-NTP Project](http://code.google.com/p/ios-ntp/). I have not personally used it, but looks like an option if auto-update is not set and you want the right(NTP) time.

Comment: Now if you do not have internet, and you want to get the right(NTP) time, I believe its not possible. I will let other SO members comment on this.

Comment: Is there any other possibilities to get exact time of a device, if user is in offline?.