# Is there an alternative to ios-ntp to get atomic/ current time ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, datetime

In my app I want to get the accurate date and time , Basically, in my application there is going to be a time sensitive portion that users can not start until after a certain time.

But if I go and grab the date and time from the device, the user can easily change the date and time on their device,  `Settings > General > Time & Date` change it here.

I also tried with GPS locations time stamp but no luck, `[CLLocation timeStamp]` is also give device time,

I have searched  all said to use [ios-ntp](https://code.google.com/p/ios-ntp/), but it is not when user not have internet connection,

I have refer following StackOverflow questions:

- [Accurate time on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16207668/accurate-time-on-iphone?lq=1)
- [Network Time Protocol for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269532/network-time-protocol-for-iphone)
- [Is there any way to get the tamper-proof date and time on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17560195/is-there-any-way-to-get-the-tamper-proof-date-and-time-on-iphone?lq=1)
- [Retrieving Current Time from Carrier in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134986/retreiving-current-time-from-carrier-in-iphone)
- [Time-based syncing for iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17329268/time-based-syncing-for-ios-app)

but not getting result I want,

Is there other way to get accurate/ actual time ?

**NOTE :**  ios have to store the currentdate some where , because when i change current system date from settings , and again set to `Settings > General > Time & Date > set automatically > ON` it will set the current accurate date, so can we get that date ?? or some trick ?

**Example :**

Suppose that In device right now time is `2014-01-01 15:04:57 +0000` ( right now **set automatically is ON**  in Settings > General > Time & Date > set automatically > ON ),
now
user set `set automatically > OFF` and change current dateto `2014-03-02 11:14:32 +0000`

SO when in app i write     `NSLog(@"cdate: %@",[NSDate date]);` it will print

`cdate: 2014-03-02 11:14:32 +0000` but what i want is to print the current actual

date  that is `2014-01-01 15:04:57 +0000`

Comment: with regard to your original requirement, can you elaborate? that is – the nature of the task, whether the time is fixed or it depends on a previous user action, and why you cannot rely - at least once - on network connectivity.

Comment: just one requirement is, get the accurate time (not a device time ) without internet connection, because i have check in iPhone to set other date and when i set date time to automatic it will load the currect time, without internet and carrier data.

Comment: @magma: i have some functionality in app that depends on current time , so must get the current time, not device time. and check with device time.

Comment: what I was suggesting is that while you're maybe focused on what you believe to be the solution to your requirement, someone could come up with a different approach altogether. by elaborating your real requirement (which is NOT retrieving the actual datetime, but rather, preventing a user from performing a given action before a given time), you would make it easier for us to see if there's a workaround.

Comment: @magma: i have some functionality in app that depends on current time , so must get the current time, not device time. and match with device time. if time differnce is more than 10 mins i dont have to do that task.

Comment: ok, what kind of functionality? can you elaborate?

Comment: That is i cant tell ( confidential),, i can tell only thing is that i have to **match the device time and current actual time**

Comment: @magma: i have updated question , can you please refer it.\

Comment: @user203108 Have you got solution for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you realise you are asking the impossible?  If you need to get the time and you don't have network connectivity, the only place to get the time from is the device.  Either you trust the device time, or you get the time from NTP.  There are no other choices.

How you handle this depends on exactly why you need to get the time.  If, there is functionality in your app that absolutely must not be enabled before a certain date, I would get the time from an external server and if it proves to be after the said date, set a flag in your defaults to say you have verified the date and the functionality is allowed, so you don't need to network connectivity thereafter.  If the networking connectivity is not there, you don't set the flag but maybe put a message up to say that you need to  connect to the Internet to enable the new functionality.

If it's just some part of a game, use device time and let them cheat if they want.

Comment: is it possible on jail break device??

Comment: @user203108 No, it's a fundamental limitation.  If you do not have a connect to the outside World, the only place you can get the time from is the device itself.